# While building the maven project getting this error

Tags: maven, liferay, liferay-6

I have created a maven project in eclipse and i am getting error in that.

```
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:6.2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:jar:6.2.3 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
Plugin com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:6.2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:jar:6.2.3 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

what should i do now??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because in maven repository Liferay plugin version 6.2.3 is missing. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/liferay/maven/plugins/